# How to install Nvidia 440 drivers on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 19.10

I want to install Nvidia 440 on Ubuntu 19.10 for my Nvidia Quadro k1000m.

How can I install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it form a PPA.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Comment: the first 2 commands run fine. but the last one shows error: `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` can you please help?

Comment: Most likely this is unrelated. https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages